# Travis CI throwing invalid token/public directory not found errors

Tags: git, travis-ci

I am building a static resume website as a fun project.

It is being built with Angular/Firebase/GitHub/TravisCI. I am completely new to the last two.

When pushing changes to my repository through Visual Studio Code, TravisCI was throwing the error "Public Directory Not Found."

I have my Firebase public directory set to "dist" which is what angular cli builds my app into.

This was my initial .travis.yml file

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - "10.4"
branches:
  only:
    - master
before_script:
  - npm install -g @angular/cli
script:
  - ng build --prod
install:
  - npm install -g firebase-tools
deploy:
  provider: firebase
  token:
    secure: $FIREBASE_TOKEN
  project: "my-project"
```

Someone suggested adding

```
skip_cleanup: true
```

under the deploy parameter. However this did not fix the issue.

So then I tried adding

```
- npm install
```

under the script parameter and it worked! but I have no idea why.

I guess what I am wondering here is why do I need that npm install line under the script parameter? Or DO I need it?

I am pretty new to GitHub/TravisCI, so I apologize if these are very basic questions/I am doing all of this completely wrong.

Comment: Try and keep questions short. This question is too verbose. ...and you got it working. Maybe remove the `angular`, `git`, and `firebase` tags? Appears to be a TravisCI inquiry.

Comment: @RonRoyston is that better? I trimmed it down a bit. And yeah I did get it working, but I don't know why it's working. Was just curious if someone could clear that up for me.